# after start of landscape activity I can not able to start another activity

Tags: android

After start of landscape activity like camera i can not able to start another activity.

Firstly i have started activity camera :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
 startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

Then i have started another activity like this:

```
    Intent target = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    String mimeType = getMimeType(fileName);
    target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)), mimeType);
    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");

    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException x) {}
```

But new activity is blinking after start and application crashed

My manifest is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

My device is samsung N-5100 android:4.4.2

this logs are repeatedly printed

```
    03-14 13:04:19.080 5668-5668/com.myapp  E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
    03-14 13:04:19.090 5668-5668/com.myapp  I/PersonaManager: getPersonaService() name persona_policy
    03-14 13:04:19.200 5668-5668/com.myapp  D/AbsListView: onDetachedFromWindow
    03-14 13:04:19.215 5668-5668/com.myapp  W/ResolverActivity: mLaunchedFromPackage=com.imyapp 
    03-14 13:04:19.240 5668-5668/com.myapp  D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/MultiPhoneWindow: generateLayout : sMinimumStackBoundForPortraitOrientRect(0, 0 - 0, 0), sMinimumStackBoundForLandscapeOrient=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)
```

Comment: Post your crash log.

Comment: Which permissions you have added in your manifest ?

Comment: Permissions added. But i don't think permission is prublem

Comment: Problem might be you have with defining intent with same name for both activity. Give a try with change intent object for both.

Comment: please post your error displayed in log /

Comment: I start camera activity and get result and then start another activity in other  method like OnClick. I don't start tow activities together

Answer (score 0):

I thing you get the error message ActivityNotFound if you get this method then change this line

```
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)), mimeType);
```

to as

```
File file = new File(fileName);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), mimeType);
```

and your problem is solved

Comment: yes you are right but the problem is in when you want to start new activity because you pass wrong  path to intent so plz try to change it if its not working then i find some new for you